# How can I add a new item and render it without the timeout? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks

I have this code, basically is for adding a new item to a list.

```
import './styles/app.css'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'


const initialList = [
  {title: 'Group 1', items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']},
  {title: 'Group 2', items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2']}
]

function App() {

  const [dale, setDale] = useState(true);
  const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);
  
  const handleAdd = (e)=>{
    setDale(false);
    const newList = list;
    newList[e.target.parentNode.id-1].items.push('New');
    setList(newList);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDale(true);
    }, 1);
    
  }

  return (<div>{dale ? <div className="App" key="app">
  {list.map((group, groupI)=>{
    return (
      <div id={groupI+1} key={groupI+1} className="dnd-group">
          <div className="dnd-title">{group.title}</div>
          {group.items.map((item, itemI)=>{
            return(
              <div draggable key={itemI+1}className="dnd-item">
                Item {itemI+1}
              </div>)
          })}
          <div className="dnd-añadir-item" onClick={handleAdd}>Add</div>
        </div>
        )
        })}
      </div>:<div>No vuic</div> }</div>
  );
      
}



export default App;
```

If I delete the timeout function and the 'dale' state the list keeps updating itself but is not updated in the render.
I want to know how to render the updated list without this absurd timeout and 'dale' state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `handleAdd` code is synchronous so this is pointless to try changing the display while it executes. What happens is:

- You change the state to `false`
- You change the state to `true` in the same synchronous function
- React steps in and compares the state before and after: `true === true` which evaluates to `true`. The state is unchanged so React does not re-render the component.

Also, when writing this `const newList = list;` you're not cloning the state as you're supposed to do, you just create a new reference on the same list.

Write this instead:

```
const newList = [...list];
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that "dale" really unnecessary, try the follow:

```
...
const [list, setList] = useState(initialList ?? []);

const handleAdd = (e)=>{
  const newList = list;
  newList[e.target.parentNode.id-1].items.push('New');
  setList(newList);
}

return (
  <div>
    { list.length > 0 ? (
      list.map((group, groupI)=> {
        return (
          <div id={groupI+1} key={groupI+1} className="dnd-group">
              <div className="dnd-title">{group.title}</div>
              {group.items.map((item, itemI)=>{
                return(
                  <div draggable key={itemI+1}className="dnd-item">
                    Item {itemI+1}
                  </div>)
              })}
              <div className="dnd-añadir-item" onClick={handleAdd}>Add</div>
          </div>
          )
        })
    ) : (
      <div>No vuic</div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

With `initialList ?? []` I'm assuming that `initialList` could be `undefined` or null, hope this works, please let me know.